# Instantiation of Socket mysteriously change the value of C String.

Tags: c, networking

I have this pierce of code

```
 char *ip_addr;
             ip_addr=(char*)malloc(10);

    ip_addr=getIPAddress(ip_addr);




 /*
  * Create a UDP socket to use:
  */


 s = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM,0);

  if ( s == -1 )
    displayError("socket()");

               memset(&adr_srvr, 0, sizeof(adr_srvr));

       adr_srvr.sin_family=AF_INET;

            adr_srvr.sin_addr.s_addr= inet_addr(ip_addr);

           adr_srvr.sin_port=htons(3000);

         len_srvr = sizeof(adr_srvr);
               bzero(&(adr_srvr.sin_zero), 8);
```

I check the ip_addr is valid from getIPAddress function, but  when the code reached adr_srvr.sin_addr.s_addr= inet_addr(ip_addr), the ip_addr becomes NULL!

I kept on debugging and zeroed in the bug on the line s = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM,0).
Therefore I modified the code to make it work.  I make the socket function comes after the inet_addr(ip_addr).  Now , the code works. ip_addr is valid when hits inet_addr line.

```
        char *ip_addr;
         ip_addr=(char*)malloc(10);

ip_addr=getIPAddress(ip_addr);




           memset(&adr_srvr, 0, sizeof(adr_srvr));

   adr_srvr.sin_family=AF_INET;

        adr_srvr.sin_addr.s_addr= inet_addr(ip_addr);

       adr_srvr.sin_port=htons(3000);

     len_srvr = sizeof(adr_srvr);
           bzero(&(adr_srvr.sin_zero), 8);




        /*
  * Create a UDP socket to use:
  */

          s = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM,0);

  if ( s == -1 )
    displayError("socket()");
```

This is very strange thing to be happened. ANyone has any idea why the Socket function affecting the value of ip_addr?

Comment: What does your getIPAddress() do ?  many IP addresses you will not fit  into 10 bytes if it's an ASCII representation (e.g. 192.168.1.19 needs 13 bytes)

Comment: getIPAddress function gets the IPV4 address in ASCII format.

Comment: @lizz ok, what about the 2. part of my question ? Is 10 characters enough for your IP addresses, including the 0 terminator ?